# why this error occurred with GoogleSignInAccount?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I'm trying to use Google Sign In Account In  but I have error this my code

```
class AuthViewModel extends GetxController{
  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
  }
  @override
  void onReady() {
    // TODO: implement onReady
    super.onReady();
  }
  @override
  void onClose() {
    // TODO: implement onClose
    super.onClose();
  }
  void googleSignInMethod()async{
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
}
}
```

and this is the error:

```
error: A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'. (invalid_assignment at [ecommerce_app_getx_mvvm] lib\core\viewmodel\auth_view_model.dart:24)
```

[image: error image]

Comment: Hi There, You need to post actual code and actual error that you are receiving.

Comment: ok I'm sorry I will Edit it

Answer (score 0):

in the last version the problem appear so I used this version google_sign_in: ^5.0.3

Comment: Didn't work for me but google_sign_in: ^4.5.1 worked.